# $(u_n,v)_H\to C_v$ implies weak convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $(u_n,v)_H$ converges for all $v\in H$, where $H$ is a Hibert space. Does this imply the existance of $u\in H$ such that ${u_n}_\overrightarrow{w}u$?

Comment: Is $H$ separable? If $(u_n)$ is bounded then this is true

Comment: @evangelopoulos F. How does separability help?

Comment: Let $c_k=\lim_n(u_n,e_k)$ where $(e_k)$ is an ONB. Show that if $u_n$ is bounded then $c_k$ is square summable and look at $u=\sum_k c_k e_k$.

Comment: @Evangelopoulos F. Good, thanks. Also, I think one can show boundedness by the uniform boundedness principle, so to assume separability is enough.

Comment: You don't need separability to apply the uniform boundedness principle.  Using this, you show that $$
v\mapsto\lim\langle u_n,v\rangle
$$
is a bounded linear functional (with physics convention for inner product) so the result follows from the Riesz representation Theorem.

Comment: @Ruy very good, this answers the question completely.